# Docker Compose setting Hostname

Tags: docker, docker-compose, httpd.conf

I have the basic `docker-compose.yml` shown below for an apache server. And I was wondering if there was a way to configure this apache server, which is currently accessible using 0.0.0.0:8889 OR localhost:8889, so is it accessible using a custom host name, such as: `local.foobar.dev` for example?

```
version: '3'

services:
    snappyweb:
      image: php:7.0-apache
      ports:
        - "8889:80"
      volumes:
        - ./:/var/www/html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want this to only work for your local dev environment.

The easiest and safest way is to use an application that will essentially trick your local browser into thinking a URL of choice is a certain IP address.  That IP could be a `locahost:8000`.

For this I use [GasMask](http://clockwise.ee/) (osX) or your can use [Host File Manager](https://github.com/scottlerch/HostsFileEditor) (Windows).

Comment: Thanks for the advice Andrew. I tried downloading it, and it seems to work okay. but it doesn't seem to take in port numbers. Any ideas why?

Comment: This worked well enough. The trick seems to be to omit the port number from the GasMask host config file and then add it to the URL in your browser, etc. as needed.

Comment: Changing your `etc/host` file only messes around with the DNS resolution and their corresponding IP addresses.   Not their ports.  In aa typical server, ports are default, 80 for public traffic.  If you want to mess around with ports I suggesting reading this SO post (https://serverfault.com/a/54371/421371).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reach your container from your host using a custom name, you will need to do the mapping between local.foobar.dev and the desired IP manually by adding the following line to **/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       local.foobar.dev
```

For communication between containers, you can create a docker network and add the containers to this network. Then containers can reach each other using container names.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I tried that. That didn't work. Same outcome. Also, trying to see if theres a docker-compose specific solution / but not required.

Comment: @AnchovyLegend Your container should be reachable using `local.foobar.dev:8889`. As for a docker-compose solution, as far as i know there isn't a solution for reaching the container from the host, but from other containers check updated answer.